# Elasticsearch query results in 'No query registered for [must]'

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-query

ES version 2.3, I'm trying to run a search on elasticsearch server with filter & query. I have several keys I would like to search with, some **has** to be a part of the results and 'host' key **should** be in the results (since I want results from multiple hosts, not just one)

This is the query I'm trying to run, for some reason I'm getting an error saying- "search_phase_execution_exception - No query registered for [must]"

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "filter": {
                "bool": {
                    "must": [{
                        "range": {
                            "@timestamp": {
                                "gte": 1503751766908,
                                "lte": 1503751786908,
                                "format": "epoch_millis"
                            }
                        },
                        "query": {
                            "should": [{
                                "match_phrase": {
                                    "host": "host1"
                                }
                            }, 
                            {"match_phrase": {
                                "host": "host2"
                            }
                            }],
                            "must": [{
                                "match_phrase": {
                                    "key1": "value1"
                                }
                            }]
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've mixed it up a little bit, try this instead:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        {
          "match_phrase": {
            "key1": "value1"
          }
        },
        {
          "range": {
            "@timestamp": {
              "gte": 1503751766908,
              "lte": 1503751786908,
              "format": "epoch_millis"
            }
          }
        }
      ],
      "minimum_should_match": 1,
      "should": [
        {
          "match": {
            "host": "host1"
          }
        },
        {
          "match": {
            "host": "host2"
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I think I didn't explain my problem correctly. I need all values to match exactly (@timestamp, key1) to either host1 or host2. The query you wrote also shows me other hosts and that wasn't my intention. Thanks!

Comment: Try again with my edited answer, i.e. with `"minimum_should_match"`

Comment: Thanks, but i'm still getting results from other hosts as well that match "key1" and "@timestamp"

Comment: Can you show a sample document that matches and which shouldn't match?

Comment: Yes, here is 2 examples, the first matches and the second doesn't (using elasticsearch-py):  Match>>> res['hits']['hits'][0]
{u'sort': [1503751767000], u'_type': u'xxxx', u'_source': {u'@timestamp': u'2017-08-26T12:49:27.000Z', u'host': u'host1', u'key1': u'value1'}, u'_score': None, u'_index': u'xxxxxx', u'_id': u'xxxxxxxxx'}


Shouldn't match>>> res['hits']['hits'][1]
{u'sort': [1503751767000], u'_type': u'xxxx', u'_source': {u'@timestamp': u'2017-08-26T12:49:27.000Z', u'host': u'random_host', u'key1': u'value1'}, u'_score': None, u'_index': u'xxxxxx', u'_id': u'zzzzzzzzz'}

Comment: Found the issue, it looks like I needed to add .raw to the host field since its an analyzed field...now your query works! thanks!

Comment: Yes, that was my next question, glad you figured it out ;-)